# Is there another way to write these queries without using temp tables?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have 3 tables (tb_cdcp_ATQchild, tb_cdcp_ATQInfant, tb_cdcp_ATQPreschool) that look similar to the first table below. Based on the IndividualID and the createdate, I need to count all IndividualIDs where the second number is lower than the first number. For example, for IndividualID = 7029AF536A9EB4B1697D, 1/18/19 has a total of 9 if you count C_Q1 through C_Q5, 1/19/19 has a total of 5 if you count C_Q1 through C_Q5, so that IndividualID would get a count of 1 since the 2nd number is lower than the first number. I have 3 tables that look just like with same logic. The 4th table- tb_cdcp_ANSchecklist - second table below - has True and False and needs to be included with the other 3 tables with the logic being a little different. So for 7029AF536A9EB4B1697D in the tb_cdcp_ANSchecklist table, 11/22/19 has a count of 6 trues and 12/3/19 has 6 falses - If there are more falses in the second entry then the first entry then that IndividualID gets counted as 1, but even if the individualid has more than one table where the second number is lower than the first number, the IndividualID only gets a count of 1. It's very confusing what I need to do, so hopefully it makes sense.

[image: tb_cdcp_ATQchild]

[image: tb_cdcp_ANSChecklist]

```
---Child Tables
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb.dbo.#temp1', 'U') IS NOT NULL
  DROP TABLE #temp1; 
select *,Row_number() Over(Partition by ATQChild_IndividualID Order by ATQChild_CreateDate) as rownum
into #temp1
from [dbo].[vCDCP_rptChildImprove]

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb.dbo.#temp2', 'U') IS NOT NULL
  DROP TABLE #temp2; 
select a.ATQChild_IndividualID,a.ATQChild_CreateDate,a.ChildSum,b.ChildSum as B_Childsum,case when a.ChildSum<b.ChildSum then 1 else 0 end as flag
into #temp2
from #temp1 a left join #temp1 b on a.ATQChild_IndividualID=b.ATQChild_IndividualID and a.rownum=b.rownum+1

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb.dbo.#temp3', 'U') IS NOT NULL
  DROP TABLE #temp3; 
select *,row_number() over(Partition by ATQChild_IndividualID,flag order by ATQChild_CreateDate) as rownum1
into #temp3
from #temp2

UPDATE #temp3
SET flag=0
where flag=1 and rownum1>1

---Infant Tables
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb.dbo.#temp4', 'U') IS NOT NULL
  DROP TABLE #temp4; 
select *,Row_number() Over(Partition by ATQInfant_IndividualID Order by ATQInfant_CreateDate) as rownum
into #temp4
from [dbo].[vCDCP_rptInfantImprove]

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb.dbo.#temp5', 'U') IS NOT NULL
  DROP TABLE #temp5; 
select a.ATQInfant_IndividualID,a.ATQInfant_CreateDate,a.InfantSum,b.InfantSum as B_Infantsum,case when a.InfantSum<b.InfantSum then 1 else 0 end as flag
into #temp5
from #temp4 a left join #temp4 b on a.ATQInfant_IndividualID=b.ATQInfant_IndividualID and a.rownum=b.rownum+1

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb.dbo.#temp6', 'U') IS NOT NULL
  DROP TABLE #temp6; 
select *,row_number() over(Partition by ATQInfant_IndividualID,flag order by ATQInfant_CreateDate) as rownum1
into #temp6
from #temp5

UPDATE #temp6
SET flag=0
where flag=1 and rownum1>1

---Preschool Tables
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb.dbo.#temp7', 'U') IS NOT NULL
  DROP TABLE #temp7; 
select *,Row_number() Over(Partition by ATQPreschool_IndividualID Order by ATQPreschool_CreateDate) as rownum
into #temp7
from [dbo].[vCDCP_rptPreschoolImprove]

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb.dbo.#temp8', 'U') IS NOT NULL
  DROP TABLE #temp8; 
select a.ATQPreschool_IndividualID,a.ATQPreschool_CreateDate,a.PreschoolSum,b.PreschoolSum as B_Preschoolsum,case when a.PreschoolSum<b.PreschoolSum then 1 else 0 end as flag
into #temp8
from #temp7 a left join #temp7 b on a.ATQPreschool_IndividualID=b.ATQPreschool_IndividualID and a.rownum=b.rownum+1

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb.dbo.#temp9', 'U') IS NOT NULL
  DROP TABLE #temp9; 
select *,row_number() over(Partition by ATQPreschool_IndividualID,flag order by ATQPreschool_CreateDate) as rownum1
into #temp9
from #temp8

UPDATE #temp9
SET flag=0
where flag=1 and rownum1>1

---ANS Tables
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb.dbo.#temp10', 'U') IS NOT NULL
  DROP TABLE #temp10; 
select *,Row_number() Over(Partition by ANS_IndividualID Order by ANS_CreateDate) as rownum
into #temp10
from [dbo].[vCDCP_rptANSImprove]

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb.dbo.#temp11', 'U') IS NOT NULL
  DROP TABLE #temp11; 
select a.ANS_IndividualID,a.ANS_CreateDate,a.ANS_DepSum as A_DepSum,b.ANS_DepSum as B_DepSum,a.ANS_ArrSum as A_ArrSum, b.ANS_ArrSum as B_ArrSum,
case when a.ANS_DepSum<b.ANS_DepSum then 1 when a.ANS_ArrSum<b.ANS_ArrSum then 1 else 0 end as flag
into #temp11
from #temp10 a left join #temp10 b on a.ANS_IndividualID=b.ANS_IndividualID and a.rownum=b.rownum+1

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb.dbo.#temp12', 'U') IS NOT NULL
  DROP TABLE #temp12; 
select *,row_number() over(Partition by ANS_IndividualID,flag order by ANS_CreateDate) as rownum1
into #temp12
from #temp11

UPDATE #temp12
SET flag=0
where flag=1 and rownum1>1
```

Comment: Did the new query work?

Answer (score 0):

You didn't really give any sample as text, so I don't think people would like to understand your code and test it. You might start with:

```
SELECT *, 
  CASE WHEN c_q1+c_q2+c_q3+c_q4+c_q5 >
       LEAD(c_q1+c_q2+c_q3+c_q4+c_q5) 
          OVER (PARTITION BY IndividuaID ORDER BY Child_CreateDate)
       THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS compareVal
FROM tb_cdcp_ATQchild;
```

I didn't understand what would you do with the rest of tables.

EDIT: And you could use CTEs instead of temp tables, which might make it easier.

Answer (score 0):

Last time I checked, booleans in SQL Server were just ints bound to [0,1]. I also assumed there is no null. Hope this works.

```
SELECT IndividualID, IIF(sum(flag) != 0, 1, 0) as flag
FROM (
         SELECT IndivisualID,
                IIF(C_Q1 + C_Q2 + C_Q3 + C_Q4 + C_Q5 >
                    LEAD(C_Q1 + C_Q2 + C_Q3 + C_Q4 + C_Q5) OVER (PARTITION BY IndividualID ORDER BY Child_CreateDate),
                    true, false) AS flag
         FROM tb_cdcp_ATQchild
         UNION ALL
         SELECT IndivisualID,
                IIF(C_Q1 + C_Q2 + C_Q3 + C_Q4 + C_Q5 >
                    LEAD(C_Q1 + C_Q2 + C_Q3 + C_Q4 + C_Q5) OVER (PARTITION BY IndividualID ORDER BY Child_CreateDate),
                    true, false) AS flag
         FROM tb_cdcp_ATQInfant
         UNION ALL
         SELECT IndivisualID,
                IIF(C_Q1 + C_Q2 + C_Q3 + C_Q4 + C_Q5 >
                    LEAD(C_Q1 + C_Q2 + C_Q3 + C_Q4 + C_Q5) OVER (PARTITION BY IndividualID ORDER BY Child_CreateDate),
                    true, false) AS flag
         FROM tb_cdcp_ATQPreschool
         UNION ALL
         SELECT IndivisualID,
                IIF(anxiety_arr + anxiety_dep + hyper_arr + exagg_arr + exagg_dep >
                    LEAD(anxiety_arr + anxiety_dep + hyper_arr + exagg_arr + exagg_dep)
                         OVER (PARTITION BY IndividualID ORDER BY CreateDate), true,
                    false) AS flag
         FROM tb_cdcp_ANSchecklist
     ) AS entries
GROUP BY IndividualID
```

A version without LEAD.

```sql
WITH child (IndividualID, flag, row_num) AS (
         SELECT IndividualID,
                C_Q1 + C_Q2 + C_Q3 + C_Q4 + C_Q5                                        AS flag,
                ROW_NUMBER() over (PARTITION BY IndividualID ORDER BY Child_CreateDate) AS row_num
         FROM tb_cdcp_ATQchild),
     infant (IndividualID, flag, row_num) AS (
         SELECT IndividualID,
                C_Q1 + C_Q2 + C_Q3 + C_Q4 + C_Q5                                        AS flag,
                ROW_NUMBER() over (PARTITION BY IndividualID ORDER BY Child_CreateDate) AS row_num
         FROM tb_cdcp_ATQInfant),
     preschool (IndividualID, flag, row_num) AS (
         SELECT IndividualID,
                C_Q1 + C_Q2 + C_Q3 + C_Q4 + C_Q5                                        AS flag,
                ROW_NUMBER() over (PARTITION BY IndividualID ORDER BY Child_CreateDate) AS row_num
         FROM tb_cdcp_ATQPreschool),
     checklist (IndividualID, flag, row_num) AS (
         SELECT IndividualID,
                anxiety_arr + anxiety_dep + hyper_arr + exagg_arr + exagg_dep     AS flag,
                ROW_NUMBER() over (PARTITION BY IndividualID ORDER BY CreateDate) AS row_num
         FROM tb_cdcp_ANSchecklist)
SELECT *
FROM (
         SELECT IndividualID,
                CAST(sum(IIF(row_num = 1, flag, -flag)) > 0 as BIT) over (PARTITION BY IndividualID) as flag, 'child' as table_name
         FROM child
         WHERE row_num <= 2
         UNION ALL
         SELECT IndividualID,
                CAST(sum(IIF(row_num = 1, flag, -flag)) > 0 as BIT) over (PARTITION BY IndividualID) as flag, 'infant' as table_name
         FROM infant
         WHERE row_num <= 2
         UNION ALL
         SELECT IndividualID,
                CAST(sum(IIF(row_num = 1, flag, -flag)) > 0 as BIT) over (PARTITION BY IndividualID) as flag, 'preschool' as table_name
         FROM preschool
         WHERE row_num <= 2
         UNION ALL
         SELECT IndividualID,
                CAST(sum(IIF(row_num = 1, flag, -flag)) > 0 as BIT) over (PARTITION BY IndividualID) as flag, 'checklist' as table_name
         FROM checklist
         WHERE row_num <= 2) AS entries
```

Comment: I added a new version without LEAD, this looks like a real monster.

Comment: Can you be more specific on the individualid for the select statement here "SELECT IndividualID, IIF(sum(flag) != 0, 1, 0) as flag FROM ( "? Since I have an individualid in all of the tables its unclear from which table it is for in the select query.

Comment: Also, for the IIF statements, I get an error "The IIF function requires 3 argument(s)"

Comment: I added the table name, but not sure which IIF is missing arguments. Can you try this one?